# Basis of the space of linear maps

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I asked someone about this problem:

> Let $V,W$ be vector spaces with bases $(\alpha_i)_{i\in I}, (\beta_j)_{j \in J}$ respectively. Define $f_{ij}(\alpha_k) = \delta_{ik}\beta_j$. Show that $(f_{ij})_{i\in I, j \in J}$ is the basis of $Hom(V,W)$.

The solution presented was something like: take some formula from nowhere and check that it's OK.

Can you show me the full path to the solution, i.e. how to arrive at some solution?

*EDIT*: my tries:
Let $\varphi \in Hom(V,W)$. We have 
$$\varphi(\alpha_k) = \sum_i \beta^*_i(f(\alpha_k)) \triangleright \beta_i$$
but $\beta_i = f_{ki}(\alpha_k)$, so
$$\varphi(\alpha_k) = \sum_i \beta^*_i(f(\alpha_k)) \triangleright f_{ki}(\alpha_k)$$

The problem is that the scalar in the group action depends on $\alpha_k$ and it should be constant.

/edit2: my try to prove the linear independence:

Suppose $\sum_{i,j} r_{ij} f_{ij} = 0$, i.e.
$$\forall {x\in V}:  \sum_{i,j} r_{ij} f_{ij}(x) = 0$$
In particular, this holds for $x = \alpha_k$. We get
$$0 = \sum_{i,j} r_{ij} f_{ij}(\alpha_k) = \sum_{i,j} r_{ij} \delta_{ik} \beta_j = \sum_{j} r_{kj} \beta_j $$
From linear independence of $ (\beta_j)_{j \in J}$ we get that $r_{kj} = 0$ for all $j\in J$. By the freedom of $k$ we get that all $r_{kj} = 0$

Comment: A linear map $f\in Hom(V,W)$ is completely determined by the image of a basis of $V$ under $f$. Use this fact to write $f$ as a linear combination of $f_{ij}$.

Comment: I tried, but my coefficients are dependent on the argument and they should be constant

Comment: Why did someone vote down?

Comment: I think it might be more helpful if you wrote down what you have tried. Anyways, it is sufficient to find a linear combination of $f_{ij}$ such that it sends $\alpha_i$ to $f(\alpha_i)=$linear combination of $\beta_j$.

Comment: Consideration of the finite-dimensional case $Hom(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^m)$ might give insight into the "formula from nowhere".  In that finite-dimensional case this amounts to asking what a basis for $n\times m$ matrices should look like.

Comment: Added my tries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I think you need $V,W$ finite dimensional for the statement to be true. For example, if you take $W=\mathbb{R}$ and $V$ any infinite dimensional real vector space, then $Hom(V,W)=Hom(V,\mathbb{R}) = V^*$, which has strictly larger dimension for $V$ infinite dimensional.

In your expression, $\beta_i^*(f(\alpha_k))$ $\textbf{is}$ a constant for any given $i,k$. So if you take the linear combination
$$
\varphi(x) = \sum_{i,k} \beta_i^*(f(\alpha_k))f_{ki}(x)
$$
This is a linear map $V\to W$ such that $\varphi(\alpha_k) = f(\alpha_k)$. Hence $\varphi = f$. You then need to show linear independence of $f_{ij}$ to conclude that it is in fact a basis.

Comment: Yes, indeed, it should be finite dimensional. I tried to prove the linear independence, can you take a look whether it's all correct?

Comment: @InvolutiveAutomorphism Yes I think it is correct.